# Smooth scrolling with external link after returning back to home page

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I have include four content in same page with smooth scrolling. When I returning back after going on another page, I could not get proper smooth scrolling due to I have added`<?php echo base_url('');?>` in href for "feedback". Others are working as I just give id for that.
Following is my code,

Html code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse menu-header-menu-container" id="brn-navbar-collapse-1"> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!--<li><a href="#brn-promo" title="Home">Home</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="#brn-overview" title="Overview">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#brn-features" title="Features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#brn-gallery" title="Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('');?>#brn-feedback" title="Feedback">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('');?>calculator_controll/about" title="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('');?>calculator_controll/glossary" title="Glossary">Glossary</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('');?>calculator_controll/faqs" title="Faqs">Faqs</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('');?>calculator_controll/disclaimer" title="Disclaimer">Disclaimer</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(".navbar-barnaul").find("a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.defaultPrevented;

    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top-75}, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Use `base_url('default_controller/default_method')` instead.

Comment: Thanks Tpojka...but feedback page is in same page with overview,features and gallery and also it is called with # that mean id. Here when first I go with about and then returning back to feedback, smooth scrolling is not working.